# How to find if value exists in column 2 given criteria for column 1?

Tags: excel

So you know how there is a sumifs function where you only sum the values in which each column's criteria is met?

What is the formula for finding if a value exists in the spreadsheet after each column's criteria is met?

For example:

```
Column A | Column B
A | Green
A | Blue
A | Green
B | Red
B | Red
B | Red
B | Green
B | Yellow
C | Blue
C | Green
C | Red
```

I want to find if Blue exists given that column A's value is "B"  In this case it does not exist.  I prefer not to use VBA if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Given I am understanding your question properly I would give this formula a try.

You can use the `COUNTIFS` function to achive your desired result.  Just place this formula anywhere except columns "A" and "B" in the same sheet.

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"B",B:B,"Blue")
```

You can nest your `COUNTIFS` into an `IF` statement to produce a more readable result.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,"B",B:B,"Blue")>0,"Found","Not Found")
```

EDIT: Included `IF` statement